# Java GameState not changing

Tags: java

When I set the event `Mouse_Clicked` it should go back to the main menu but does nothing when I click on the mouse. I want it to go to `MENUSTATE` which is the main menu but nothing happens. I need help since this is a school project and I don't know what is wrong.

```
package GameState;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import main.GamePanel;

public class HelpState extends GameState {
    private Color titleColor;
    private Font titleFont;

    public HelpState(GameStateManager gameStateManager) {
        init();
    }

    @Override
    public void init() { }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics2D g) {
        g.setColor(titleColor);
        g.setFont(titleFont);

        g.clearRect(1, 1, GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT);
        g.drawString("Move Left: Left Arrow ", 0, 25);
        g.drawString("Move Right: Right Arrow ", 0, 45);
        g.drawString("Attack: A Button ", 0, 65); 
        g.drawString("Become Other Wumps: You must have things happened to", 0, 85);
        g.drawString("you (Eg. Get smashed by a wall). After that you must press ", 0, 95);
        g.drawString("the corresponding No. Key.", 0, 105);
    }

    private void select() {
        gsm.setState(GameStateManager.MENUSTATE);
    }

    public void mousePressed(int m) {
        if (m == MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED) {
            select();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(int k) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(int k) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your program even get into mousePressed(int m){}?

Comment: Try adding @Override to your mousePressed(int m){} method, see what happens.

Comment: `g.clearRect(1, 1, GamePanel.WIDTH, GamePanel.HEIGHT);` is a bad idea, as the actual width and height could be different from what you think it is, also, Java is generally zero indexed, meaning that you probably should be starting at `0x0`.  Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0):

You should implement MouseListener to get input from mouse.

If you want to check a button is pressed I recommend you to use ActionListener. If you need extra properties from that click use MouseListener.

Example MouseListener:

```
 import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

 public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
       saySomething("Mouse pressed position "
                    + e.getPoint(), e);
    }
```